# Per category permissions

Tags: google-groups, permissions

I would like to have separate categories in my Google Groups, one for the production team and one for all of the members. The `Member` should not be able to see posts in the `Product Team` category.

Is there a way to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

Google Group doesn't have a permissions access for categories. See [Permissions](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2465496?hl=en) for a list of all permissions available in Google Groups.